# 繰り返しのときの代入の持ち越し？について

Tags: ruby

eachなどで繰り返しをする際に2回目以降、最後に代入した変数を使用して配列の中から一つをランダムに除外したものを表示したいのですがなかなか上手くいきません。
以下のようにしているのですが、繰り返し2回目になるとエラーが出てしまいます。

```
(1..5).each do |num|
    if(num - 1 == 0)
        puts "1回目"
        no_fruits = nil
    else
        puts num.to_s << "回目"
        no_fruits = no
    end

fruit1 = "apple"
fruit2 = "orange"
fruit3 = "strawberry"
fruit4 = "kiwi"
fruit5 = "cherry"
fruit6 = "banana"
fruit7 = no_fruits

all = [fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, fruit4, fruit5, fruit6, fruit7 ].reject {|item| item == fruit7 }
p all

no = all.sample
p no
end
```

結果↓

```
1回目
["apple", "orange", "strawberry", "kiwi", "cherry"]
"strawberry"
2回目
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from test.rb:12:in `<main>'
        1: from test.rb:12:in `each'
test.rb:18:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `no' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  not
```

となり上手くいきませんでした。
一応以下のようにすればそれっぽいことはできましたが、無理やりやっている感じがします。

```
(1..5).each do |num|
    if(num - 1 == 0)
        puts "1回目"
        fruit1 = "apple"
        fruit2 = "orange"
        fruit3 = "strawberry"
        fruit4 = "kiwi"
        fruit5 = "cherry"
        fruit6 = "banana"
    else
        puts num.to_s << "回目"
        fruit1 = "apple"
        fruit2 = "orange"
        fruit3 = "strawberry"
        fruit4 = "kiwi"
        fruit5 = "cherry"
        fruit6 = "banana"
        fruit7 = [fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, fruit4, fruit5, fruit6].sample
        puts "除外 = " << fruit7
    end

all = [fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, fruit4, fruit5, fruit6, fruit7].reject {|item| item == fruit7 }
p all
end
```

もっと他に良いやり方があればぜひ教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: これで良いのかどうか判然としませんが、[`inject()` を使う方法](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eWbhQJLvEGSFkjzG)はどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(1..5).each do |num|
  if(num - 1 == 0)
    puts "１回目"
    no_fruits = nil
  else
    puts num.to_s << "回目"
    no_fruits = no
  end

#略    

  no = all.sample 
  p no
end
```

ループ末尾の`no = all.sample`で`no`が定義されますが、これはループ内にしかスコープなので、ループ末尾に到達すると消えてしまいます。なので、ループ2回目の`no_fruits = no` で`no`を参照しても、この時点では定義されていないので、`undefined local variable or method`になるわけです。

なので、外側のスコープで変数を定義してやれば、次のループに変数を持ち超すことができます。

単純にはこうです。

```
no = nil # ''でも1でも

(1..5).each do |num|
#(略)
end
```

ただこれだと、`no`はループないでしか使わないのにその後ずっと生き残ってしまうので、あまりきれいではありません。

コメントでinjectメソッドに触れられていますが、

```
(1..5).inject(nil) do |no, num|
   (略)

   all.sample
end
```

こうすると、ループ末尾の`all.sample`の値が次のループの時は`no`に入っている、という動きになります。injectメソッドについては[リファレンス](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Enumerable.html#I_INJECT)見てみてください。

ただ、2つめのコードを見ると、「前回ループで抽出したもの」は絶対の条件ではないように見えます。であれば、

```
all =  [fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, fruit4, fruit5, fruit6]

(1..5).each do |num|
  if num == 1
    p all
  else
    p all.delete_at(rand(all.length)) #ランダムに1個取り除いたものを表示
  end
end
```

とかでもいいような気がします。

Answer (score 1):

> 最後に代入した変数を使用して配列の中から一つをランダムに除外したものを表示したい

これは、「用意した配列から要素をランダムに除外して、そのあとの配列の中身を表示させるループ処理を書きたい」という理解であっているでしょうか？

であれば、次のように書くことができるかもしれません：

```rb
def random_sampling(array, count = 1)
  # 終了条件を設定
  return nil if array.size.zero?

  #
  # 関数内の処理本体部分
  #

  element = array.sample

  puts "#{count}回目"
  p array
  puts '-' * 30

  # 再帰処理
  # * array から取り出した element を除外
  # * 何回目かカウントする変数をインクリメント
  # ...をしつつ同じ関数を呼び出すことで、処理結果を引き継いで再実行
  random_sampling(array - [element], count.succ)
end

target = %w[apple orange strawberry kiwi cherry banana]

random_sampling(target)
# =>
# 1回目
# ["apple", "orange", "strawberry", "kiwi", "cherry", "banana"]
# ------------------------------
# 2回目
# ["orange", "strawberry", "kiwi", "cherry", "banana"]
# ------------------------------
# 3回目
# ["strawberry", "kiwi", "cherry", "banana"]
# ------------------------------
# 4回目
# ["kiwi", "cherry", "banana"]
# ------------------------------
# 5回目
# ["kiwi", "banana"]
# ------------------------------
# 6回目
# ["kiwi"]
# ------------------------------
```